# Unable to Extract JavaScript Elements while Scraping Quora

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, quora

I am trying to extract Data from Quora for analysis purposes using Python, BeautifulSoup and Selenium. But I am unable to extract the JavaScript elements on the page. How should I extract them?

Here I am only trying to extract bio of the Quora Profile but I am not getting the text which comes after clicking the 'more' button.

~https://i.stack.imgur.com/20q72.jpg

```
                # Extracting Bio
                driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui_qtext_more_link').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                bio = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_qtext_rendered_qtext").text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below line of code to first click on the "more" button and then fetch the expanded text of the profile.

```
import time
//Fetch the more button element first
WebElement moreButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[@class='ui_qtext_more_link'])[1]");    
//Click on the more button
moreButton.click();
time.sleep(3)
//Fetch the profileInfo element
WebElement profileInfo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[contains(@id,'expanded_content')]//span[@class='ui_qtext_rendered_qtext'])[1]");
//Store the bio in a string and use it further
String profileInfoBio = profileInfo.text;
```

Comment: I used the above code on 6 different profiles and it extracted Bio of only 2 of them. For the others the output was something else which was not in the bio.

Comment: Can you give me the profile names for which the code was not working ?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/profile/Abdelrahman-Hamdy-1
https://www.quora.com/profile/Purnima-Borgohain
https://www.quora.com/profile/Nikhil-Chandwani

These are some profiles for which the code doesn't work

Comment: I have edited the code, please check now and please fetch the new element after clicking on every different profile. Let me know if it works

Comment: Yeah its working now. The only thing you changed was adding a delay. So how come it was working for some profiles but not for others. Also, I was doing something similar with my code but using "find_element_by_class_name", you used Xpath. Whats the difference between these two methods, can you please tell me?

Comment: Yup i added the delay, because i found out that after clicking on more button, sometimes the data was taking sometime to load because of which you were getting incorrect data from the given xpath. So adding the delay, worked!!